# What are some good books for classical mechanics of continuous systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, continuum-mechanics

I am trying to learn classical mechanics for continuous systems. Goldstein contains only one chapter on it. Is that chapter sufficient or is there more to the subject? If yes, what are some good books to learn the same?

Comment: "Theoretical Mechanics of Particles and Continua" by Fetter and Walecka has more than one chapter devoted to the study of continuous system, so it passes your minimum requirement, but I haven't read it thoroughly so I cannot comment on its quality. But the book itself should be quite cheap as you can buy an edition from Dover Publications.